# Can I deploy automatically to AWS ElasticBeanstalk? SSH or so?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a simple PHP application, which doesn't use any database, or anything else. I have a script, which asks me for version name and than creates ZIP with the site and upload via the web interface.
Can I upload to ElasticBeanstalk via let's say SSH?

Comment: Have you tried deploying it using git?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, with the [Elastic Beanstalk Configuration Files](http://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2012/10/02/introducing-aws-elastic-beanstalk-configuration-files/).